# How to select the cell that matches a search on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I often have gigantic spreadsheets that have many cells that I need to update. But I also like to use the keyboard as much as possible (i.e. using keyboard shortcuts) and avoid using the mouse to be more efficient.

A common situation I have where I have to switch between keyboard/mouse is when I search for a term, and it finds it, but then I have to click on that cell with my mouse first before I go back to the keyboard.

Is there a way to select that cell directly using the keyboard?

Comment: Yes I am using Ctrl+f and no it doesn't return me to the cell

Answer (score 2):

Solution is simple. Basically whenever you search for something and it gets highlighted, you must press the <kbd>esc</kbd> key, then the cursor is placed at the search term, and you can go from there.